# Windows app signing

Tags: windows, code-signing

I want to sign a windows application. I'm using kSign for this.
On the computer where I signed the app, it appears signed when I exectute it but on 2 other computers (all under windows 10) the application appears unsigned at the first execution. If I go to the file properties, display signing details and execute the app again, it appears signed.
Does anybody had the same problem ? How can the app appears signed without going to the file details ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using signtool (included in Windows SDK) instead of Ksign. signtool uses SHA1 whereas kSign uses SHA256.